# Yet another issue with a homebrew update => python upgrade => "No module named 'praw'" (missing site-packages)

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

Sorry for the repeat, if any, but this is driving me nuts. I ran through a few upgrades of homebrew, in the past, and all python scripts I used to use were running fine, post python updates, meaning the upgrades got all necessary site-packages properly accounted for.

Upgrade today (same mechanism: brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup --prune=all), and I see my new python version at 3.12.2 having replaced my previous 3.11, but missing tons of stuff in /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (as compared to 3.11). Some of them are the praw ones, thus the obvious "No module named 'praw'" when trying to run a python script dependent on it.

I do recall having had a similar issue, a while ago, which I thought I fixed with some simple pip install --upgrade praw or python -m pip install --upgrade praw, but these are now coming back with the "error: externally-managed-environment".

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of [PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/), which Homebrew has [followed along with](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3404).  It is now documented [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/externally-managed-environments/#externally-managed-environments).

> This PEP proposes a mechanism for a Python installation to communicate
> to tools like pip that its global package installation context is
> managed by some means external to Python, such as an OS package
> manager. It specifies that Python-specific package management tools
> should neither install nor remove packages into the interpreter’s
> global context, by default, and should instead guide the end user
> towards using a virtual environment.

So.  [As of Python 3.12, Homebrew is following PEP 668](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python#pep-668-python312-and-virtualenvs).  It is not broken.
Your choices are:

- Install Homebrew-packaged copies of the modules you want.  If Homebrew does not package them, then you can work to [add them to Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Adding-Software-to-Homebrew#formulae).
- [Create a `venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), and use `pip` to install the modules you want inside the `venv`.  Activate the `venv` when you want to use it.

Comment: Maybe it‘s covered in one of the links, but what should the OP now do to update the libraries?

Comment: Install the Homebrew-packaged copies of the software/libraries, or create a `venv` and install with `pip` there.  This is where Python is going.

Comment: The question ends with „Any ideas how I could fix this?“, adding the steps to do so would for sure help.

Comment: OP here: it would, indeed, help to be directed to a fix.

Comment: Who'd have thought that the experience of working with Python could get worse?