Learning Python, can't install scikit-learn
On my Windows machine, I ran pip3 install scikit-learn and it installed without any problems, however, on my Mac, I've tried a lot of things:
$ brew list                                                                                                                            [17:21:35]
==> Formulae
ca-certificates glib        libidn2     libunistring    little-cms2 ncurses     pipx        tree-sitter zstd
cairo       gmp     libimagequant   libuv       lua     neovim      pixman      unibilium
fontconfig  graphite2   liblinear   libvterm    luajit      nmap        python@3.12 utf8proc
freetype    harfbuzz    libmpc      libx11      luv     numpy       readline    watch
fribidi     htop        libpng      libxau      lz4     openblas    scikit-image    webp
gcc     icu4c       libraqm     libxcb      lzo     openjpeg    scipy       wget
gettext     isl     libssh2     libxdmcp    mpdecimal   openssl@3   sqlite      xorgproto
giflib      jpeg-turbo  libtermkey  libxext     mpfr        pcre2       tcl-tk      xsimd
git     libevent    libtiff     libxrender  msgpack     pillow      tmux        xz

==> Casks
android-file-transfer   firefox         iina            microsoft-teams     transmission-remote-gui wireshark
dozer           freecad         inkscape        shadowsocksx-ng-r   visual-studio-code  zoom
dropbox         google-chrome       jellyfin-media-player   steam           vlc
eddie           google-earth-pro    microsoft-auto-update   teamviewer      warp
 
atom@macbook-pro: ~
$ brew install scikit-learn                                                                                                            [17:21:38]
Warning: No available formula with the name "scikit-learn". Did you mean scikit-image?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
scikit-image ✔

To install scikit-image ✔, run:
  brew install scikit-image ✔
FAIL

atom@macbook-pro: ~
$ pip3 install scikit-learn                                                                                                            [17:21:44]
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
    use a virtual environment:
    
    python3 -m venv path/to/venv
    source path/to/venv/bin/activate
    python3 -m pip install xyz
    
    If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with
    
    brew install pipx
    
    You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
    the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
    'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
    will permanently disable this error.
    
    If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
    pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
    file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.
    
    Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
FAIL

atom@macbook-pro: ~
$ pipx install scikit-learn                                                                                                            [17:21:52]
Note: Dependent package 'numpy' contains 1 apps
  - f2py

No apps associated with package scikit-learn. Try again with '--include-deps' to include apps of dependent packages, which are listed above. If
you are attempting to install a library, pipx should not be used. Consider using pip or a similar tool instead.
FAIL

I've also tried the commands on the official website, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html, which produce similar errors as my system doesn't recognize pip and the -U flag doesn't make a difference.
What am I doing wrong?

I think it's explained in the above output, but to summarise: The package isn't available in homebrew (I checked for scikit-learn package and it doesn't exist in homebrew's formulae)... So you need to install your package using a python package manager such as pip. But to do that, you need to enter a virtual environment THEN use pip install scikit-learn... HOWEVER, a simpler way to install the scikit-learn package without needing to enter a virtual environment is to use pipx instead. The thing is, pipx isn't installed by default, so you need to brew install pipx first...

I already have pipx installed and, as shown in the output above, tried to run pipx install scikit-learn. I'd like to do it without a venv to keep things simple since I only have one project, but if it's required to run I guess I'll bite.

Did you try pipx install --include-deps scikit-learn?

I get the same results in a virtual environment.

I've just installed pipx (took me forever because it needed some other package dependencies!)... and got the same error as you if I ran pipx install scikit-learn... HOWEVER, if you run pipx install --include-deps scikit-learn, it should work (it did for me at least). hope that helps!

@AVelj yeah that works but I can't access or find the environment where it's installed on vscode

Did you run pipx ensurepath to automatically add it to your environment? That's the message I got when I installed it successfully. It should be located in ~/.local/bin/

Yes, I ran that command

Just updated my previous comment, the package should be located in ~/.local/bin/... Can't help anymore unfortunately (off to see a friend). Good luck!

How do I pull up hidden folders in vscode to pick them as the interpreter?

all I want is to run a script with sklearn, why is this so difficult >.<

Never used VSCode so I don't know unfortunately... but can't you just add a line in your VSCode to cd into ~/.local/bin/? Definitely you can cd into it in terminal using cd ~/.local/bin/. You could even run the program directly by entering ~/.local/bin/f2py in terminal.

Does this answer your question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470627/yet-another-issue-with-a-homebrew-update-python-upgrade-no-module-named/470632#470632

@ohshitgorillas, did you get it working in the end?

@AVelj Yes, I ended up using the venv created by VSCode rather than my own. It was easy to install once I was in the new venv. For some reason, selecting a custom-made interpreter in VSCode defaults to using homebrew's version or something. I don't understand it but my problem is fixed so I'm moving on.
